# C2DM authorization key CRLF and .Net WebRequest

Tags: .net, android-c2dm

We are using C2DM and are writing the server app in C#.

We obtain the authorization key with a POST using the WebRequest component. This works and we get back an encoded authorization key. The problem comes when we add this key to the auth header of the request that is going to send the message.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");
...
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "GoogleLogin auth=" + AuthorizationKey);
```

Since the key has the LF character, we get an exception...

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Specified value has invalid CRLF characters.
Parameter name: value

   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckBadChars(String name, Boolean isHeaderValue)

   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
```

It would seem that CheckBadChars() is refusing the authorization key because it thinks there is a CRLF in the key, when in fact there is only a LF.

Does anyone have any ideas how we could get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you’re just getting a linebreak at the end that you’re supposed to remove?

**Edit:** I read the documentation (at http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html#Response) and it says you’re supposed to get back a response that looks like this:

```
SID=DQAAAGgA...7Zg8CTN
LSID=DQAAAGsA...lk8BBbG
Auth=DQAAAGgA...dk3fA5N
```

There’s your three linebreaks. So what you need to do is pick out the the line starting with `Auth=` and grab the authorization token from there.

Comment: No, we have 3 LF and 0 CR in the key.

Comment: Added likely solution to answer.